# How To Copy A Cell So Value Is Not Lost When Applying Filters Without Using Mouse

Tags: vba, excel

I was looking for a way to copy a cells contents so that after I filter or un-filter the sheet I would not lose the copied value.  I did not want to use a mouse to select the formula bar and copy the value from there.  I like having F2 set up to edit the cell directly and thus did not want to change the excel settings to use F2 to jump to the formula bar.

I decided a VBA Macro run via a shortcut would be a good solution.

I did not see this solution anywhere else on the site so wanted to share how I achieved this.  See my solution below for the code I used to achieve this.

Comment: What are you doing with the copied value(s)? You could alternatively store them in an array, which avoids the clipboard altogether.

Comment: @BruceWayne Typically I am using Ctrl + P to move the value to another cell or often to a non microsoft program / application.  So having the value on the clipboard is useful for me - but yes, could certainly be adapted to store somewhere else depending on the individuals desire / usage.

Comment: You could alternatively store the address of your cells (or cell?) in some global variable. Then you can easily fetch this value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below I save in a module titled "Copy_Cell_To_Clipboard" in my PESONAL.XLSB

```
Sub Copy_Active_Cell_To_Clipboard()

 Dim MyData As Variant
 Set MyData = New DataObject

 MyData.SetText ActiveCell.value
    MyData.PutInClipboard

End Sub
```

I then assign a shortcut to the macro [Developer Tab --> Macros --> Select the module with this code --> Options --> Choose Shortcut Key Combination]

This shortcut then allows me to copy a cells contents, without using the formula bar or a mouse and retain the copied value after using filters.

Comment: Would it not be easier to select the desired cell then hit `Ctrl-C` (windows) to copy the contents to the clipboard? It seems a bit overkill to write code to duplicate a built in function. Later, when you need to paste the value into a destination somewhere (in Excel or any other Windows application), you simply hit `Ctrl-V`, and _magic_™ happens.

Comment: @FreeMan If one uses Ctrl+C to copy a value and then clears filters from the worksheet, the value is no longer stored by Excel and cannot be pasted.  The workaround I was using was to use a mouse to click into the formula bar and copy the value from there, but this allows me to leave the mouse out of things.

Comment: @FreeMan - Agreed, especially since OP, per their comment on the main post, is using the `CTRL+P` shortcut (which is usually reserved for printing on just about all OSes), I'd avoid using a macro when there's already a built-in solution.  We may be working on an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/)

Comment: @BruceWayne I'm not using `CTRL+P` as the shortcut for the macro, I meant that after using the macro to store the values, I typically am pasting it somewhere after un-filtering the data or in a web browser / another application

Comment: Interesting problem. Maybe filtering works differently when you just have "data" vs a "table" (list object). I use Excel tables extensively and have never had any issue with that. I just tested it out with Excel 2016 - filtered a table, copied a value with `Ctrl-C`, unfiltered the table and pasted the value elsewhere with `Ctrl-V`. Congrats on a workaround that works for you, but I think this is a bit of an X-Y problem - why doesn't Excel work for you like it's supposed to?

Comment: @FreeMan Certainly may only be useful to smaller niche group - figured it wouldn't hurt to share in case someone else could benefit.  For reference I'm on Excel 2010 and typically not using tables.